# Non-failing timeout using ctest

Tags: cmake, ctest

I am specifying a test in my CMakeLists.txt which runs an executable and is supposed to look for a specific output (the `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`) to determine success.

Since the binary doesn't terminate itself, I would also like to terminate the executable after some `TIMEOUT`.

The test should pass if my `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` occurs before the `TIMEOUT`, otherwise it should fail.

My CMakeLists.txt looks lie:

```
add_test(NAME sometest COMMAND my_binary)
set_tests_properties(sometest PROPERTIES 
                     PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "All systems go[.]"
                     TIMEOUT 10)
```

Unfortunately, having a `TIMEOUT` **always** marks the test as failed. Is it possible to specify a non-failing timeout?

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to the same problem. This usecase doesn't seem to be supported by ctest.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for a solution of the similar problem, and I found it [on the CMake mailing list](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2019-June/069652.html):

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_test(NAME mytest 
         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DMYEXE=${PATH_TO_MYEXE} -DARG_TIMEOUT -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ExecuteTest.cmake)
```

ExecuteTest.cmake:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${PATH_TO_MYEXE}
                TIMEOUT ${ARG_TIMEOUT}
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE output)

if(NOT output MATCHES "^my_desired_regex$")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "myexe did not produce desired output")
endif()
```